# Capture a Date value from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a string like below,

```
var text1 = "TEST 01DEC22 test";
```

I want to capture only the "01DEC22" date from the string; I tried and was successful if only the text contained the date only, as shown below.

```
 var text = "01DEC22";
 var results = Regex.Matches(text, @"^(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|([3][0-1]))(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\d{2}$").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

Kindly help me how to retrieve the value if it is contained within a string.

Comment: why did you put `^` and `$`? do you know what they mean?

Comment: Remove `^` and `$`.

Comment: You have put `^` at the beginning which means the "Start of the string", and `$` at the end which means the "End of the string". Do you think `TEST 01DEC22 test` starts and ends with a date string like `01DEC22`? As already suggested in the previous comments, your pattern will work after removing `^` and `$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments just remove the `^` and `$` but you seem to have a careful way of checking for the day of the month instead of just `\d?\d` but with your method you still accept `0DEC22` as a date.

You can simplify the regex to this which only accepts valid days of the month:

`(0?[1-9]|[12]\d|3[01])(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\d\d`

This would be even simpler if you aren't worried about invalid dates:

`(\d?\d)(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\d\d`

Answer (score 4):

If the dates are to be in two digits always, you may use below regex

```
((0[1-9])|([12]\d)|(3[01]))(JAN|FEB|MAR|APR|MAY|JUN|JUL|AUG|SEP|OCT|NOV|DEC)\d\d
```